# How to get JSON value from Javascript using JINT library

Tags: javascript, c#, json, jint

I have this JavaScript file:

```
var input = {
  "CONTRATE": 0,
  "SALINC": 0,
  "RETAGE": 55.34,
  "MARSTATUS": "single",
  "SPOUSEDOB": "1970-01-01",
  "VIEWOPTION": "pension"
};

var inputValidation = "input.CONTRATE > 50 && input.SALINC < 50 && input.RETAGE > 50";

eval(inputValidation);
```

**How to get JSON value of "input" variable using JINT as JSON object string?**

Answer (score 5):

I believe we can achieve desired result in 3 ways

**Method 1 - Use Jint's Built-in Parser**

Jint has built-in parser to support `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` functions for javascript. we can use them for this task:

```
        var engine =new Engine();

        var json = @"{
              ""CONTRATE"": 0,
              ""SALINC"": 0,
              ""RETAGE"": 55.34,
              ""MARSTATUS"": ""single"",
              ""SPOUSEDOB"": ""1970-01-01"",
              ""VIEWOPTION"": ""pension""
            }";

        var input = new JsonParser(engine).Parse(json);

        var result= engine
            .SetValue("input", input)
            .Execute("input.CONTRATE > 50 && input.SALINC < 50 && input.RETAGE > 50")
            .GetCompletionValue().AsBoolean();
```

**Method 2 - Use 3rdParty Json Serializer**

Jint accepts POCO objects as input, hence we can first convert a json to POCO then feed it to Jint for results (for this example, I used Json.net as a Deserializer)

```
        var input = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        var result= engine
            .SetValue("input", input)
            .Execute("input.CONTRATE > 50 && input.SALINC < 50 && input.RETAGE > 50")
            .GetCompletionValue().AsBoolean();
```

**Method 3 - Put JSON object in evaluation script**

Or as Mr.Ros (author of Jint) suggested we can put JSON object and condition in the same script and pass it to Jint for evaluation.

```
        var engine = new Engine();

        var js = @"
         input={
          ""CONTRATE"": 0,
          ""SALINC"": 0,
          ""RETAGE"": 55.34,
          ""MARSTATUS"": ""single"",
          ""SPOUSEDOB"": ""1970-01-01"",
          ""VIEWOPTION"": ""pension""
        };

        input.CONTRATE > 50 && input.SALINC < 50 && input.RETAGE > 50;";

        var result = engine
            .Execute(js)
            .GetCompletionValue().AsBoolean();
```

Comment: You can also paste the JSON object directly in the script with the condition. It will be evaluated as an object inside the script. Or if it is passed as a string, use `JSON.parse` instead of doing it from C#.

Comment: JSONParser does not work when JSON has Space in the key names. Like { "First Name" : "Test"}>
Is there a way to handle this ?